# Remote Desktop Certificate Template Application Policy Extension

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, certificate, certificate-authority

We are setting up remote desktop authentication with the use of certificates and ran into an issue in one of the environments.  I am editing the `RemoteDesktopComputer2008` certificate template, in particular the `Extensions` tab and `Application Policies`.  The issue is that when we add an application policy and name it `Remote Desktop Authentication` giving it the object identifier of `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.54.1.2` and save it the `Intended Purpose` column shows the object identifier and not the Name.  This does not happen on any of the other environments and prevents it from working correctly.  When you pull the certs extensions it does not have anything for enhanced key usages which I would expect to see Remote Desktop Authentication.

We are using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with the CA installed on the Domain Controller.